# "He has yet to" vs. "he is yet to"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs

> 1. He **has**  yet to receive an appointment.
> 2. He **is** yet to receive an appointment.

Is there any difference in meaning? Is one more correct than the other?

Comment: You want *has yet to receive* because it means "has not received up to this point." *Is yet to receive* does not make sense.

Comment: @JLG: *He is to receive* and *he has to receive* are both grammatical, but don't mean the same thing. Why should adding *yet* change this?

Comment: @PeterShor, It does change things...do you think "He is yet to receive an appointment" is a sentence a native English speaker would say? I would say, "He is to receive an appointment," meaning that he should be given an appointment, but not "He is yet to receive an appointment."

Comment: In written English, both are recorded and, I believe, both are acceptable. Note that "He is to receive X" is an acceptable idiom which must be taken into account.  Ngrams suggest that up until the middle of the 19th Century  cnstructions with "is" predominated, particularly in passive contexts ("is yet to be given"). Constructions with "has" moved ahead between about 1840 and 1920, with the change coming somewhat later in AmE and passive constructions than in BrE and Active constructions. "Has" surged across the board about 1960.

Comment: @JLG: "The best is yet to come." or "The best has yet to come."?

Comment: @PeterShor, That is an apples to oranges comparison to the OP's sentences.

Comment: @JLG  It's idiom; it doesn't have to "make sense" analytically if it makes **sense** synthetically.

Comment: @JLG: How is it different? He has not yet received an appointment, and the best has not yet come. I think they're both perfectly grammatical constructions, and as StoneyB says, they've both been used for over 200 years, although "has" currently predominates.

Comment: @PeterShor, How would you answer the OP's question? Are you saying you would prefer "He is yet to receive an appointment."?

Comment: @JLG: I would say that "He has yet to receive an appointment" is the preferred form, but that they mean the same thing and "He is yet ..." is a less common alternative.

Comment: @JLG: I use "I am yet to [verb]" all the time. I certainly didn't invent it, and I remember getting called out on it exactly once, by Robusto in our chat (and even he agreed that it was grammatical, just not common). I submit that this construction is venerable, whether or not it is part of your idiolect, or indeed popular in the least. COCA has three cites for "am yet to [v]", four cites for "he is yet to [v]", and likely more if we dig deeper. Which we should. Or, as Shakespeare put it, "Sir, the event / is yet to name the winner".

Comment: @PeterShor: ♫ *"... and babe, won't it be fine."* ♪

Comment: @StoneyB: "is yet to be given" is just passive voice. It still predominates even today. :-) That's not the same as "is yet to give".

Comment: @ЯegDwight: Hey, don't drag me into this silly argument. I'm just here to sing.

Comment: @ЯegDwight - the constructions I used (in a variety of persons and numbers) were "yet to give" for active, "yet to be given", alongside the original and lexically related "yet to receive" (I don't recall the technical term for the relationship).

Comment: The two forms sound similar when spoken and can be contracted to "He's yet to ...". Is that perhaps why they both seem acceptable?

Comment: FWIW, as a native speaker of British English for many years, I see nothing at all odd about a construction such as _He is yet to receive_.

Comment: @JLG: Why would you say *is yet* doesn't make sense? Looks like Abraham Lincoln was not a native speaker:) ["The hour is yet to come, yes nigh at hand"](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/l/lincoln/lincoln1/1:126.1?rgn=div2;view=fulltext)

Comment: @Noah, That is not the same as the OP's sentences. I think it's because you are introducing two time frames. *He is to receive an appointment* means that he is supposed to receive an appointment in the future. I can live with that sentence. But adding *yet* makes it all awkward. When you say *He is yet to receive an appointment* you are saying, I guess, he has not received an appointment that he is supposed to receive in the future. I just wouldn't ever say it that way.

Comment: It seems like all the [Google results](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22He+is+yet+to+receive%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for "He is yet to receive" are from Indian or British publications, so perhaps this is an AmE vs. BritE difference. Or perhaps I have an idiotic idiolect as was implied in one of the earlier comments.

Answer (score 12):

The string *has yet to* is 7 to 8 times more frequent than *is yet to* in both the Corpus of Contemporary American English and the British National Corpus. The preference is clear, but both are grammatical and there is no difference in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

"He has yet to receive an appointment" states that the person being referred to has not, at this point in time, "received an appointment", but is expected to.

"He is yet to receive an appointment" does not, at least to me, make grammatical sense. It would possibly make more grammatical sense to say "He is yet to be a person who has received an appointment", although Googling the phrase "he is yet" with quotes yields very little evidence (besides a bible verse) that the phrase is used regularly.

Comment: In some cases, *has* seems preferable: "I have yet to hear Ray’s version of what happened."  In other cases, *is* is more familiar: "The best is yet to come."

Comment: The reasoning here takes the additional step of conjugating the verb ("to receive") that was in its infinitive form in the original sentence, which seems arbitrary. Without taking that step, "He is to receive an appointment", I think, sounds perfectly grammatical and makes sense, with a meaning that is truly in line with the original. "He has to receive an appointment", on the other hand, has a completely different meaning, and so makes "has yet" sound a bit off to me (unless "yet" is something that can be had). I am not a native, so my comment is based on logic and might not be natural.

Answer (score 1):

As StoneyB noted in his [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83430/he-has-yet-to-vs-he-is-yet-to#comment165843_83430), this answer is simply based on what sounds right to *me*, rather than what may make any grammatical or syntactic sense.

When referring to something that *will* happen, but has not happened yet, I would use the phrase "has yet". This is your first example, and it implies that you are waiting for such a thing to happen.

That is not to say that the second example isn't used, but simply would be in a different context. Let us use the example sentence, "He is to disable the alarm."
This sentence would most likely be used in a context of some sort of briefing, describing planned events in the future.
(Also, note that this does not make use of the word "yet". This sounds wrong to me and I expect it may not be grammatical.)

Comment: 'He is to disable the alarm' is an active construction, not a passive one.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Oh, of course it is! I wasn't thinking when I posted this, apparently.

Answer (score -2):

"He has yet to receive an appointment" seems to me that the person referred to is expecting an appointment to come his way; whereas "He is yet to receive an appointment" appears that the person referred to has received one or several appointments, but has not indicated the one he will select.

Comment: This answer can be improved by citing a reputable reference which upholds your claim. As it stands, your answer could be taken as a pure statement of opinion and is liable to be downvoted or deleted.