# "Has yet to win" vs. "has yet won"?

Tags: grammar, past-participles

I was doing some SAT English problems and came across [this one](http://www.cracksat.net/sat/identifying-sentence-errors/question-45-answer-and-explanation.html):

Find the error in the sentence, or state that there is no error. Each possible error is in parentheses.

> Chess players find that playing against a computer is helpful (to
>   improve) (their) skills, (even though) no chess-playing computer has
>   yet (won) a championship.

I picked up the idiomatic error: "is helpful to improve" should be "is helpful in improving". However, I also saw a problem with the last choice, because I remember hearing the words "has yet to win".

According to the solution, I'm wrong. "Has yet won" is correct. The website says this:

> There is no error at (D). The word "won," the past participle of the
>   verb "to win," combines with the word "has" to produce the appropriate
>   verb tense.

However, this means that "has yet to win" is incorrect due to the conflicting tenses.

Is "has yet to win" gramatically incorrect? Or are both okay?

Comment: You need "has yet won" there because of the negative, *"no* computer." Saying that "A computer has yet to win" is another way of saying the same thing; the negative is implicit, as least as far as the *present* and *past* are concerned, in "has yet to." But the "no" is a given here, so that is not an option.

Comment: Isn't the negative implicit in "has yet won" as well?

Comment: Nope. That is why the "no" is there, and has to be there.

Comment: @descrip No, not implicit. The negative is required for “has yet won” to work (you can’t say “A computer has yet won”), but it has to **explicitly** be there in the sentence. With _has yet to win_, it’s the other way around: it’s implicit in the construction and therefore it **mustn’t** explicitly be there in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Has yet to [infinitive]* is perfectly correct, and there is no conflicting tenses in it. Remember, the verb *have* can combine with a past participle to form perfect constructions (present perfect and past perfect, respectively, for present and past *have*), but it can also combine with a *to*-infinitive.

Usually, *have to X* means ‘must X’, but if you add *yet*, the meaning changes. It is in fact a slightly different collocation of verbs, and [it works with both *be* and *have*, though *have* is much more common](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83430/he-has-yet-to-vs-he-is-yet-to). The meaning of *X is/has yet to happen* is “X has **not** happened yet”.

This is why it does not fit your sentence here: “No chess-playing computer has yet to win a championship” means “No chess-playing computer has not yet won a championship”… and that’s frightfully difficult to parse. Presumably it would mean that *every* chess-playing computer has won a championship already, but it’s basically nonsensical.

The following two are more or less equivalent, though:

> …even though no chess-playing computer has yet won a championship.
>   …even though chess-playing computers have/are yet to win a(ny) championship(s).

The way this idiomatic phrasing works is probably easiest to understand if you use *be* as the basis: “He is to do it” means either *a)* ‘he must do it’ or *b)* ‘it is expected/known that he will do it’. Consider “He is *about* to do it”—that means that he will do it in just a moment. *Yet* here means ‘still’, so if you say “He is *yet/still* to do it”, it means that it is still expected/known that he will do it; in other words, *he hasn’t done it yet*.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to look a this is to simply accept 'to have yet to' as an idiom. However here is my attempt at a partial explanation.

*I have won*  is past perfect. The winning has already taken place.

*I have to win* is an idiom that refers to the future. These days it is synonymous with *I must win.*

By inserting 'yet' we revert it to its original sense of futurity but without a sense of compulsion.

So, *I have yet to win*, means *I have not won yet. I may (or may not) win in the future*.

I'm not sure if that helps. I hope so.